# Dynamic project setup in TeXlipse

Tags: output, texlipse

I'm using TeXlipse, and it has this default setup:
The input file is `document.tex` and the output file is `document.pdf`.

This leaves me with a lot of files named `document`. Having more than one project open at a time becomes confusing, I have to change the name of the pdf before sending it to people and it's generally annoying. You can of course change this manually every time you create a project, but I'm lazy enough to think there must be some other way.

I assign a project name anyway, why couldn't it just be `<projectname>.tex` and 
`<projectname>.pdf` by default? Also, having the builder to always put the `*.pdf` files in, for instance, `Documents` instead of in the project directory would be great.

Is there any way to set this up? Is there any reason not to?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change the filenames in an existing project, simply right-click on the project-folder --> Properties --> Latex Project Properties and there you can adjust the names for the Main tex file and the pdf.

If you create a new project, just click “Next” instead of “Finish” when you selected your document type (article, blank, etc.)

Your idea with automatically named by projectname seems not to be adjustable without looking in the sourcecode and recompiling the plugin on your own. You need to adjust the file `TexlipseProjectAttributes.java` in the `wizards` directory

Comment: I am comfortable enough with java for that to be a good solution for me, but I can't seem to find that file. A system wide search for `TexlipseProjectAttributes.java` returns nothing, and the only folder named `wizards` I find is only `.class`-files, none of which seems to be related to TeXlipse at a first glance. What am I looking for on a Windows system?

Comment: You can find the source code on the TeXclipse homepage: http://texlipse.sourceforge.net/release.html The path inside the source-zip is /plugins/net.sourceforge.texlipse.source_1.5.0/texlipsesrc/net/sourceforge/texlipse/wizards/

Comment: I found the lines I needed to change in a couple of the files in the wizards directory. How would I go about using it now? Compiling turns out to be somewhat complicated...

Comment: Sorry, I have absolutely no experience in compiling Eclipse-Plugins on my own.